# Date shows one day before from selected date in angular

Tags: angular, date, moment-timezone

Date showing one date before from selected date how to fix it?

My code sample is

```
let ds = this.prdate.formfileds[0].var;

let mv = moment(ds,'MM-DD-YYYY');

let stv = mv.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: what is format for this `this.prdate.formfileds[0].var;` ?

Comment: DD-MM-YYYY format

Comment: Show your full code

Comment: @user17559335 it's not possible to help you without seeing the code. The problem might has something to do with timezones so check them out. Just to give you an example of what sort of problem it might be....  when user selects date in Europe on December 1st at 3:00 am (at night:)) in the US it's November 30th at that time, so the day before.

Comment: sorry now only saw your comments.
In my html page:
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" (click)="picker1.open()"  class="dateclass">
                      <input readonly matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" 
                      placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" (click)="picker1.open()"
                      formControlName="var"  dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" >
                      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                          <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
                      </mat-form-field>

Comment: <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-3">
        <button   type="submit"  (click)="onSub()" class="btn btn-suc mr-2 btn-sm"><i class="mdi mdi-file-document"></i>Save</button>
       </div>

Comment: import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms'
import * as moment from 'moment';
export class PrTaxFormComponent implements OnInit {  Prdate:FormGroup;  constructor(private fob: FormBuilder) {
this.rows = this.fob.array([]);
this.Prdate = this.fob.group({
 var: ['', Validators.required], });
onSub(){
let dateString = this.Prdate.formfileds[0].var; 
let momentVariable = moment(dateString, 'MM-DD-YYYY');  
let stringvalue = momentVariable.format('YYYY-MM-DD');   
console.log(stringvalue); 
 this.Prdate.get('var').setValue(stringvalue); }
}

Comment: edit your question with code please, it is unreadable in comments.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this.aa = this.prdate.formfield[0].var;
var prdatefield = new Date(Date.parse(this.aa));
var prmonth = prdatefield.getMonth() + 1;
var prdate = prdatefield.getDate();
var pryear = prdatefield.getFullYear();
var finalprdate = prmonth + '/' + prdate + '/' + pryear;
console.log(‘prdate ',finalprdate);

Comment: I have fixed that issue like above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code.

```html
let date = new Date();
console.log('NATIVE JS DATE TIME', date.toString());
console.log('STRINGIFIED TIME', JSON.stringify(date));
console.log('FORMATTED TIME', `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`);
```